# Docker image build fails to connect to npm registry

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install

I have run into a problem with my docker image where building the image fails due to failure to install the npm requirements. The logs simply mention a failure to connect ('EHOSTUNREACH') and the build hangs and stops. It's important to note that the same exact Dockerfile worked before and I have changed literally nothing about my setup. Last night I managed to build properly and today it failed.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:18.17.0

# set work directory
ENV ProjectDir=/app
RUN mkdir -p $ProjectDir
WORKDIR $ProjectDir
COPY . $ProjectDir

RUN npm install --verbose --omit=optional
RUN npm run build --verbose

# set environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npx", "serve", "build" ]
```

I've verified that the build fails to connect to the npm failure by adding `RUN curl -v https://registry.npmjs.com/` to the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by a temporary shortage I can't explain, since it fixed itself overnight.